# Android Studio doesnt recognize content of imported jar archive

Tags: java, android-studio, jar, archive

I read all over the net on how to import a jar file to android studio because I want to import parts of a java program I previously wrote into my android app.
So I already tried the following:

- Put the jar into the libs folder and add `compile files('libs/my-jar.jar')` to the build.gradle (actually I tried both files, the one in app and the one in ´appname´).
- Rightclick the jar and clicked "Add as Library"
- Cleaned and rebuild (both via commandline and from within Android Studio)
- Added the jar via "Project Structure -> Dependencies"

I litterally tried every suggestion on simmilar posts here on stackoverflow I found by googling "use jar in android studio" or "import java archive android studio" etc.

My Problem is, that Android Studio doesnt find the classes within my jar.
It still underlines my code whenever I try to create an Object of one of my classes. Im currently using Android Studio 1.2.1.1.

Do I somehow have to import them in Java Syntax (eg. `import my-jar.jar.ClassXY`?

I have no experience with java archives. I just exported my Java project from Eclipse by hitting "Export -> As Jar Archive". I also tried exporting as runnable jar file. Is that theoretically enough? When I searched the web it seemed to me this is enough.

Thank you for answers :)

Comment: Try this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/35343238/5475941][1]. I explained different approaches for importing JAR files into Android studio. I hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35343238/5475941